# netbeans editor loses focus on editor and gives it to the menubar

Tags: netbeans, editor

I am newbie of using Netbeans and i have Netbeans 6.5 on XP. So, here is my problem: when i am working on Netbeans and switch to an another task and then come back later, editor of the Netbeans losts the focus and the menubar gains it. I don't want to press ALT key again to re-focus on the editor. I made some search on help contents of the Netbeans and google and i couldn't find any solution. Have any of you got an idea to solve this problem? By the way, i am sorry about my unfluent English. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Try Ctrl-0. It should set the focus to the editor window. There are several focus-related keyboard shortcuts. Look through the Window menu for the shortcuts to the different windows.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [this thread](http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic6082.html). I ended up using a different look-and-feel, but updating your JDK might just help, too.

Comment: Also, might want to update his version of Netbeans, 6.5 is around a year old.